# How can I easily diff/compare 2 shelvesets in TFS?

Tags: tfs, shelving

Is there a way to compare 2 shelves in TFS without having to resort to unshelving both in separate workspaces and diffing the files?

Comment: Could you please mention which method worked and how exactly? Thanks!

Comment: I went with tfpt review in the end.

Comment: but as Ian Goldby's comment on the accepted answer states, this doesn't compare the shelveset with the local copy, but the shelveset and the original version/the latest version...?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have access to TFS currently, but if the file in the shelveset has a unique idenitifer (like say $/x/y/z/a.b.c;SH='ShelvesetName') you should be able to issue a command line [tf dff command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/difference-command) to compare each one.

**Or**

If you unshelve one and then use the command line TFS power tools to compare the other one with the review command

```
tfpt review /shelveset:shelvesetName;userName
```

The power tools are version specific and you can download the following versions:

- [TFS Power Tools 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)
- [TFS Power Tools 2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2013Power)
- [TFS Power Tools 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=35775)
- [TFS Power Tools 2010](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinWoodward.TeamFoundationServerPowerToolsDecember2011)
- [TFS Power Tools 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=15836)
- [TFS Power Tools 2005](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=10443)

Comment: The tfpt review command doesn't seem to be able to compare against your local disk. The Diff button gives you the changes from the original version, and Diff Latest gives you the changes from the latest version on the server. Neither is what the original questioner asked for.

Comment: Down voted because it says 'you should'. So it's a guess then?

Comment: The documentation states that you can only compare a shelveset to a server version, not your local files OR another shelveset. So unless someone proves that it works, both statements in this answer are wrong :/

Comment: The tfpt link seems dead. Can you try [this one](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1/file/177107/1/tfpt.msi?SRC=VSIDE) and confirm?

Comment: Neither of these suggestions works. tfpt review cannot compare a shelveset to local changes, and tf diff cannot compare two shelvesets.

Comment: The question was about a shelvesets and the what you originally had, but and not a shelfset and local changes.

Comment: As others have said, down-voted because `tf diff` only compares to server version, not local files, so for comparing two shelvesets, that options does not work.

Answer (score 32):

I was looking for the same i.e. to compare the contents of two shelveets without needing to unshelve one of them. End up writing a Visual Studio extension for the functionality.

The extension is available for Visual studio 2013

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1fa59764-efc6-457a-a5f3-81ca68e280e8

and for Visual studio 2012

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/33c521d4-73fc-48be-969d-fa68c511341f

Please feel free to use and give your feedback.

Comment: Very nice, good sir.  You have made the world a better place.

Comment: @Hamid any chance you are updating that for VS 2015?

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper There is a version available now for Visual Studio 2015. There were bugs reported so I had to take it offline to fix them.

Comment: awesome tool. do you have an upgrade for VS2015?

Comment: There is a VS2015 version available

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HamidShahid.ShelvesetComparer

Comment: @Hamid any chance you are doing a VS 2017 update? :)

Comment: The Visual Studio 2017 version of shelveset comparer extension is now available 

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HamidShahid.ShelvesetComparer-19329

Comment: @Hamid Woo! Thanks

Comment: Found @Hamid DiffFinder for VS2022 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dprZoft.DiffFinder-VS2022, successor to ShelvesetComparer. Did exactly what I needed it for.  Thanks!

Comment: Lovely. Thanks for the amazing work !!

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio you can go to Team Explorer, Pending Changes, Actions - Find Shelvesets, then find your Shelveset, right click and View ShelveSet Details, you end up with a list of file, right click the one you're interested in and choose Compare with Workset.